# SVG text cut off in Firefox, independent of CSS/HTML structure

Tags: svg

Page passes validator, works in IE9 and Chrome. But I'm clueless why the text get cuts off in Firefox? I've tried playing with the CSS, changing the width and height of the label (didn't do anything), changed the absolute position of the label (still got cut off at the exact same spots), pretty much tried anything HTML/CSS wise.

Screenshot:
http://i44.tinypic.com/10qjp5t.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the svg element width and height attributes both set to 100%.

Comment: Giving a width and height indeed worked! Thanks. Do you also happen to know why the Menu page doesn't work with a doctype, but does work without in both firefox and IE?

Comment: Nvm, started replacing everything with Rafael JS library for cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Add the property "background-size", and give it the width and height values of your SVG image, like this: background-size: (width)px (height)px;

So if your SVG has a width of 100px and a height of 50px, use the following rule in the CSS for your SVG:
background-size: 100px 40px;

Furthermore, to add support for older browsers, define a fallback png background in the CSS for your SVG before the SVG background, in the following way (and order):
background: url(fallback_image.png) no-repeat;
background: url(svg_image.svg) no-repeat;

This works because most browsers that support SVG, support multiple background as well, and thus the latter background (SVG) will be applied. If the browser doesn't support SVG, it will just use the first background (non-SVG).

Source: http://css-tricks.com/using-svg